# How can I stop my integers from displaying as HEX?

Tags: c++, integer, hex

I am practicing some code implementing different data structures. For this example I am trying to implement a simple stack data structure. So far it works as intended, but I keep getting Hex characters when trying to display my stack. Could anyone help me with figuring out why this is the case?

Also I am trying to get better at structuring my code properly, can anyone that is already involved in the industry please give me some constructive criticism as to what I have coded so far. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// stack_MAX == maximum height of stack
const int stack_MAX = 10;

class stack{
    public:
        stack(){
        //Constructor initializes top of stack
            top = -1;
        }

        bool isFull(int top){
        //isFull() will check to make sure stack is not full
        //Will return TRUE if stack is FULL, and FALSE if 
        //stack is NOT FULL
            if(top == stack_MAX - 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        bool isEmpty(int top){
        //isEmpty() will check to make sure stack is not empty
        //Will return TRUE if stack is EMPTY, and FALSE if
        //stack is NOT EMPTY
            if(top == -1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        void push(int x){
        //push() will push new element on top of stack
            if(isFull(top)){
                cout << "Sorry, but the stack is full!" << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                top++;
                x = stk[top];
            }
        }

        void pop(){
        //pop() will pop the top element from the stack
            if(isEmpty(top)){
                cout << "Sorry, but the stack is empty!" << endl;
                exit(1);
            }
            else{
                cout << stk[top] << " is being popped from stack!" << endl;
                top--;
            }
        }

        void display_stack(){
        //diplay_stack() will show all elements currently in the stack
            int temp;   //will temporarily hold position of stack
            temp = top;
            while(!isEmpty(temp)){
                cout << stk[temp] << endl;
                temp--;
            }
        }
    private:
        int top;
        int stk[stack_MAX];
};

int menu(){

    int choice;

    cout << "Welcome to my stack!" << endl;
    cout << "What would you like to do? (select corresponding #)" << endl << endl;

    cout << "1. Push" << endl;
    cout << "2. Pop" << endl;
    cout << "3. Display" << endl;
    cout << "4. Quit" << endl;

    cin >> choice;

    return choice;
}

int main()
{
    int selection, x;

    stack myStack;

    selection = menu();

    while(selection != 4)
    {
        switch(selection){
            case 1:
                cout << "please enter number to be pushed: ";
                cin >> x;
                myStack.push(x);
                selection = menu();
                break;
            case 2:
                myStack.pop();
                selection = menu();
                break;
            case 3:
                myStack.display_stack();
                selection = menu();
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Oops that's not a selection, try again" << endl;
                selection = menu();
                break;
        }
    }

    cout << "Thank you for stopping by and using my stack!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which outputs are giving hex and did you do `std::cout << std::hex` anywhere?

Comment: The last line of your push(int x) method is reversed. Also if you use `using namespace std` I highly recommend that you rename your class to something other than `stack` since `stack` is part of STL and when your code gets larger as you include more header files, you may encounter a naming conflict.

Comment: Also choose and stick with one naming convention. Having camelBack and under_score variables in the same code is not a good practice (isEmpty() vs display_stack())

Comment: Use `const` wherever a variable is being used that is not meant to be altered. If you had originally defined your `push` method as `push(const int)`, the compiler would have caught the problem in your code.

Comment: I'll pile on with some additional advice: when asking a question that's essentially "why am I getting unexpected output?", you should always try to give an example of the wrong output, the expected output, and the input used to generate the wrong output.

Comment: Wow thanks everybody for the feedback! I eventually would like to become a software engineer so practicing how to code the right way is very beneficial to me. I am working on building a tree I'll apply some of the things you guys mentioned here to that project. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by prehistoric penguin, your push() function is incorrect:

```
x = stk[top];
```

Should be changed to:

```
stk[top] = x;
```

I wanted to comment anyway to offer some general comments as you requested:

- If statements like this can be replaced by a single line of code:

  ```
      if(top == stack_MAX - 1)
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  ```

becomes:

```
return (stack_MAX - 1 == top);
```

- Put constant expressions on the left-hand side of your comparison expression. For example:

  `(top == stack_MAX - 1)`

becomes:

```
(stack_MAX - 1 == top)
```

The reason is that one day you will accidentally type something like:

```
(top = stack_MAX - 1)
```

and you or somebody else will waste a lot of time debugging it :)

- Your isFull() and isEmpty() functions shouldn't take a parameter. They should just use the private member variable top. How would somebody call these functions without access to top, which you've correctly made a private member?
- In general, avoid `using`. In my opinion it defeats the whole purpose of namespaces. using namespace std is a commonly used exception, but even then, is it so hard to type std::cout?
- Always put curly braces around the clauses of your if statement, even if they are just one line. It's easy to forget to add braces if you need to add more statements to a clause later on, which can be quite confusing.
- Your code formatting is pretty good, but pick a bracket style and be consistent. Either always put the opening curly brace on the same line as the function header / control statements etc, or always put it on the line afterwards.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

A statement in your `push` functin is wrong, modified as below:

```
void push(int x)
{
    //push() will push new element on top of stack
    if(isFull(top))
    {
        cout << "Sorry, but the stack is full!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        /***************************
        x = stk[top];
        ****************************/
        stk[top] = x;
    }
}
```

Advice:

- Learn to debug, here is the **[tutorial](http://dirac.org/linux/gdb/)**
- Include the head file `cstdlib` when you want to use `exit` in your
  code
- Do not name your class with the same name for any classes in STL